# Google accounts (and apps not syncing) on RealMe 3 Pro (Android 10)

Tags: applications, google, realme

I have 5 Google accounts on my phone running on RealMe UI (Android 10). None of my Google accounts are getting synced I tried removing one of the account and adding back but then only Gmail synced but still not getting any mail notifications. I have tried all the solutions such as rebooting, re installing, turning off power saver mode. Problem is even if a uncheck and check the auto sync option nothing is happening.

Please find me a solution for this, as sync is extremely necessary because I need to get my notifications from Gmail Google classroom and Google calendar.

Answer (score 1):

First use browser to log in to Gmail. If you are successfully log in to Gmail. Then it is confirm that problem with Gmail app.

Update Gmail apps.
Go to app setting / gmail / storage / clear data and clear cache.

Comment: I have done everything installing/ uninstalling, nothing is working. Problem is none of the Google apps are getting synced, in day to day life I use Google Keep, it is also not syncing with the google account. Thing is I'm getting mails on all the IDs but not receiving any notifications.

Comment: I've faced this twice now. It was fixed when I cleaned google play services and google play store data.

Comment: Update: The issue is with phone storage. That is, if out of 64GB only 5GB is free then Google Notifications might not come.

Comment: So the last time it happened was months back, and I had to factory reset it. It worked well so far, but the problem resurfaced again today. Funnily, I googled and found this page, and realized that I've been here before.
Anyway It might be the storage problem as you said, I was indeed low on storage, and after clearing some space. sync is working for now.
I wonder why devs are not working on this very apparent bug.

Comment: I spent quite a bit of time trying to fix the issue on my Realme GT but the only thing that did the trick was free up some memory as suggested by @sahil-jhawar (I was at 5% free memory and magically bringing it to 30% it worked!)